# Ionic Framework AngularJS - Cannot call services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a mobile Apps using the Ionic Framework. I am not sure why the app.controller('DrawObstaclesCtrl'... under the bindEvents function (Please see the code below) cannot be invoked. However, the bindEvents function itself can be invoked. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with my code? It is driving me crazy. Your help will be much appreciated :)

My index.html page has the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="./js/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/mainApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="starter">
        <ion-modal-view>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-scroll zooming="true" overflow-scroll="false" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"
                            scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false">
                    <div> </div>
                    <div class="scroll-container" id="draw_area" style="width: 100%; height:100%; background: url('PathFindingMap.png') no-repeat ">

                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-modal-view>

        <button style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;" id="button1" class="control_button" type="button">Search!</button>

        <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="algorithm_panel" class="panel right_panel">

            <div class="accordion">

                <h3 id="astar_header"></h3>

                <div id="astar_section" class="finder_section">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="play_panel" class="panel right_panel">

        </div>
        <div id="stats"></div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

My mainApp.js file has the following code:

```
 var app = angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

My controller.js file has the following code:

```
 app = angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

      // I did not post all the codes because there are too many. 
      // bindEvents method can be invoked.
     bindEvents: function () {

    alert("Hi bindEvents is invoked");
    try {

        app.controller('DrawObstaclesCtrl', function ($scope, ObstaclesService) {
            alert("Your controller work");
            var coords = ObstaclesService.getObstaclesCoordinates();
            // to loop through coordinate values
            for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
                var x = coords[i];
                var y = coords[i + 1];
                View.setAttributeAt(x, y, 'walkable', false);
            }
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
```

My Services.js file has the following code:

```js
app = angular.module('starter.services', [])


app.factory('ObstaclesService', function () {
    function storeCoordinate(x, y, array) {
        array.push(x);
        array.push(y);
    }

    var coords = [];
    storeCoordinate(1, 1, coords);


    return {
        getObstaclesCoordinates: function () {
            return coords;
        }
       
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ Ionic, but why is your `app.controller('DrawObstaclesCtrl'...` code inside a method? Shouldn't it be run along with the rest of the `app.whatever()` (eg, `app.factory()`) code snippets? Also, I wouldn't expect the `alert` to run until the view associated w/ the controller is loaded. Is this your understanding as well?

Comment: Agree with @therobinkim. You shouldn't put angular controller inside any event.

Comment: Actually I have no choice so I have to put angular controller inside an event. Is there really no other way to put controller inside an event.?

Comment: `bindEvents` throwing error

Comment: Perhaps I haven't used Angular enough, but can you explain why you want your Angular controller inside an event? I am having a hard time thinking of why you DON'T want a controller to exist until a certain time. I looked through http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html and didn't find any indication that Ionic requires controllers to be created as a result of async events.

Comment: Hi @therobinkim, it is because I am using a third party pathfinding.js library. The code they gave me is using javascript events. Each event is executing some actions. For example, the bindevent method is executing the "drawing the obstacles on the map". But I wish to put the codes of the "drawing the obstacles on the map" in a Services. That is why I put a controller inside the bindevent method, so it can call the "drawing the obstacles on the map" in the Services. However, I tried not to put controller in an event but it is too complicated to modify the whole code.

Comment: Hmm actually i can put all the codes in the controllerjs into servicesjs. But is that fine? Because the controllerjs contains many events code, so i am not sure whether servicesjs can contain event binding code, etc.

Comment: @Antoni That *works*, but you should probably keep your controller code inside your `controller.js`